# Timeout waiting for a process in Golang without killing it?

Tags: go

I'm using `context.WithTimeout()` and `exec.CommandContext()` to start a process and wait for some amount of time for it to complete, as described here: https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#CommandContext

However, this kills the process when the timeout fires. I want to leave the process running instead, so that I can do other tasks and use the stdout/stderr output later.

Is this possible?

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: If you do not want to cancel the command do not use CommandContext. What is the question? What have you tried? What didn't work out?

Comment: Just use: https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Start

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the timeout to kill the process, why use `CommandContext`?

Use the `Start` method instead, or `Run` in a separate goroutine. Here's an example of `Start`:

package main

```
import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "5")
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("Waiting for command to finish...")
    err = cmd.Wait()
    log.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
}
```

Where the "waiting for finish" line is printed, your code is free to do whatever it wants, while the started process keeps running in the background.